# envfit nmds error Error in prod(np) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument

Tags: r, vegan, phyloseq

I am trying to run an NMDS using as input the abundances of phyloseq object:

```
ps_abu<-microbiome::transform( psxxx, "hellinger") %>% 
    abundances()%>%
    t()
set.seed(123)
nmds = metaMDS(ps_abu, distance = "bray", trymax=1)

however when I try to get the envfit I get this error: 

enfit = envfit(nmds, env, permutations = 999, na.rm = TRUE)
Error in prod(np) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument
```

Unfortunatly, I dont have a reproducible example, but could it be possible to correct the error? it seems the nmds I creat is not creating correctly

Comment: There is no way to tell without more information. The output from `metaMDS` is usually substantial. Did you get any warnings/error messages when you created `nmds`? What is `env`?

Comment: tthe nmds gets created and it returns a list that seems correct,
this is the env: 
```ènv <- psxxx %>%
  meta() %>%
  select(Location, pH, N, C, OM, P, K)
```
and it is a data.frame

Comment: If `env` is a data frame with variables and `nmds` is a `metaMDS` result, your command will work. As it fails, either `env` is not a valid data frame, or `nmds` is not a result from successful run of `metaMDS`.

Comment: I don't know if it adds to the discussion - 9 months after the date - but in my case there was a variable in env that had a lot of NA observations -> given that envfit calls `complete.cases` both on the ordination matrix and env, it could be attributed to that - when I removed that specific variable, the issue was resolved.